# $_POST with the same name in a fetch_assoc

Tags: php, post, submit, fetch

Hello everyone
Today I got an interesting question (at least for me). I'm creating divs and inputs 
in a fetch_assoc and I was wondering about the best way to submit all of these inputs. They are 
with the same name but they have different values and sometimes the same.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT IDBewoner, Foto FROM Bewoners LIMIT 5";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$totaalbewoners = mysqli_num_rows($res);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
?>
<tr>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>" name="bewoner"></td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['Foto'])."' width='90' height='90'>" ?> </td>

    <td> 
        <div id="rang1" class="DropZone"></div> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang1input" name="rang1value" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="rang2" class="DropZone"></div> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang2input" name="rang2value" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="rang3" class="DropZone"></div> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang3input" name="rang3value" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="rang4" class="DropZone"></div> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang4input" name="rang4value" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="rang5" class="DropZone"></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang5input" name="rang5value" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="rang6" class="DropZone"></div> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang6input" name="rang6value" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="rang7" class="DropZone"></div> 
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang7input" name="rang7value" />
    </td>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form> 
</tr>

<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    /*for($i = 0; $i < $totaalbewoners; $i++) { [!!DANGEROUS CODE!!]
        $rang1bewoner.$i = $_POST["rang1value"][$i];
    }*/ 

    $rang1 = $_POST["rang1value"];
    $rang2 = $_POST["rang2value"];
    $rang3 = $_POST["rang3value"];
    $rang4 = $_POST["rang4value"];
    $rang5 = $_POST["rang5value"];
    $rang6 = $_POST["rang6value"];
    $rang7 = $_POST["rang7value"];
    $bewonerID = $_POST["bewoner"];

    /*echo "<script>alert('Bewoner: $bewonerID')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang1: $rang1')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang2: $rang2')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang3: $rang3')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang4: $rang4')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang5: $rang5')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang6: $rang6')</script>";
    echo "<script>alert('Rang7: $rang7')</script>";*/

}

}
?>
```

I first put the `if $_SERVER["METHOD_REQUEST"]` under the fetch_assoc but only got like the values 
of the first row. Then I put it in the `while fetch_assoc` (as you can see in my code), but didn't work 
either and got the same values over and over again. Then I tried to change the name of the input 
to `name="rang6value[]"` and then in the php code i wrote that `for` using the total rows as a
 
maximum (you can see it in the comment in php) and my browser crashed (it was funny tho).
**So now the question is:** How can I get all of the values of the input fields in an easy way for 
all of the rows? If you can help me with that my life would be much better. 
Thank you very much in advance. ^^

**UPDATED: THE INSERTING CODE:**

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $rang1 = $_POST["rang1value"];
    $rang2 = $_POST["rang2value"];
    $rang3 = $_POST["rang3value"];
    $rang4 = $_POST["rang4value"];
    $rang5 = $_POST["rang5value"];
    $rang6 = $_POST["rang6value"];
    $rang7 = $_POST["rang7value"];
    $bewonerID = $_POST["bewoner"];


    if(!empty($rang1)) {
        $insert1 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang1', '2015-04-14', 1)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert1);
    }

    if(!empty($rang2)) {
        $insert2 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang2', '2015-04-14', 2)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert2);
    }

    if(!empty($rang3)) {
        $insert3 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang3', '2015-04-14', 3)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert3);
    }

    if(!empty($rang4)) {
        $insert4 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang4', '2015-04-14', 4)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert4);
    }

    if(!empty($rang5)) {
        $insert5 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang5', '2015-04-14', 5)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert5);
    }

    if(!empty($rang6)) {
        $insert6 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang6', '2015-04-14', 6)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert6);
    }

    if(!empty($rang7)) {
        $insert7 = "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema
                   (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr)
                   VALUES
                   (4, '$bewonerID', '$rang7', '2015-04-14', 7)";
        $res = $mysqli->query($insert7);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: change all the name atributes to `name="rang_value[]"` than do a `for`

Comment: I did that but my browser crashed... maybe it's in my for?
Can you show me how you'll do it? you can see my for in the code, it's in comment.

Comment: why you are checking $_POST inside while loop  ? why you have save button for each row ?

Comment: @AyyanarG I know it's wrong but I tried to check the $_POST outside the while loop and only got the first 7 values for the first row.
That's why i tried to put it in the loop but I was getting the same values over and over again. I'll change it once I figure out a solution for this.

Comment: change name as madalin suggesed and do foreach for $_POST

Comment: you need a multidimension array see my improved answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try revising your form to include your `IDBewoner` *(Whatever a good unique field is, this field may not be unique, I don't know, hard to tell)* value in a double array, something like:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT IDBewoner, Foto FROM Bewoners LIMIT 5";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$totaalbewoners = mysqli_num_rows($res);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
?>
<tr>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>" name="bewoner[]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Foto']); ?>" width='90' height='90'>
        </td>
        <?php for($i=0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
            $owner_id   =   $i.$row["IDBewoner"]; ?>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang<?php echo $owner_id; ?>" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang<?php echo $owner_id; ?>input" name="rang[<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"]; ?>][<?php echo $i; ?>]" />
        </td>
        <?php }
    } ?>
        <td>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

Would give you an array similar to *(I didn't fill in any values thats why they are all blank)*:

```
Array
(
    [bewoner] => Array
        (
            [0] => 122840745
            [1] => 1972681560
            [2] => 971451812
            [3] => 1882323675
            [4] => 1165412341
            [5] => 2086561009
            [6] => 1194305395
            [7] => 2031974218
            [8] => 654763098
            [9] => 1105106609
            [10] => 399644802
        )

    [rang] => Array
        (
            [122840745] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [1972681560] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [971451812] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [1882323675] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [1165412341] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [2086561009] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [1194305395] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [2031974218] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [654763098] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [1105106609] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

            [399644802] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                )

        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

This is how you process the sql. Note, you should sanitize or bind the values, but I didn't include anything like that:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $sql['cols']    =   "INSERT INTO `ActiviteitenSchema` (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr) VALUES";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_POST['rang'] as $key => $value) {             

            $z = 0;
            foreach($value as $rang) {
                    if(!empty($rang)) {
                            $vals[$i][] = "(4, '".$_POST['bewoner'][$i]."', '".$rang."', '2015-04-14', '$z')";
                        }
                    $z++;
                }

            if(isset($vals[$i]))
                $sql['vals'][]  =   implode(", ",$vals[$i]);

            $i++;
        }

    if(isset($sql['vals'])) {
            $statement  =   $sql['cols'].implode(", ",$sql['vals']);
            $res        =   $mysqli->query($statement);
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: First I gotta say I'm amazed by the way you just wrote 7 divs in one php trick.
But how would the submit be like? Because I'm kinda confused by the way you did it; it seems really interesting tho..

Comment: Well you could submit on a row by row basis, but you could also put the submit outside of the while loop because each `rang` will have a unique `IDBewoner` in the POST array. I will edit

Comment: Ok that would be the code there. Then you will see how the post array looks when you submit the form.

Comment: I'll try this out and tell you what happens. Thank you very much for your help! I'll try this now w8 a min ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. If you want can you give me a last tip of how the inserting of these array would be? If you don't have time I completely understand. Thank you very much again

Comment: Give me a minute to look at it. What is your output on processing? Like what do you want to get from it? An SQL statement?

Comment: I edited my question and put the inserting code. That was the old way and will not work with your proper way. The values will be added by a drag-n-drop system. The adding of the values is in JQuery and it already works, but I need to insert the values in a database when I submit the form you know? 
Your way is perfectly fine and much much better than mine, but I'm really confused about the way of inserting the values in the database...

Comment: Alright, check out my sql compiler. You can edit as you see fit.

Comment: Omg thank you so much for your effort I don't know what to say to thank you!! Really thank you very much.
I have a question: will the rang column in the sql table always be 1? Or will it change depending on which rang you add? 
E.g If you add rang2 to the table the Rangnr column will turn into 2

Comment: Oh, no, sorry I didn't notice that. It's just the key. I will revise.

Comment: Wait I didn't see the errors, they were in the bottom of the page:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'cols' 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'vals' 
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Is that normal?

Comment: No. Can you post what you have so far? I don't get those errors

Comment: This is the way of adding the values.
http://gyazo.com/e451f850f8cc79f6616676efc0fd5f70
 If I post the form without adding anything I only get this error:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'cols'

 If I add some values and then post the form I get these errors too:
Illegal string offset 'vals'
 Cannot use string offset as an array http://gyazo.com/754bd4196d7b944e8f9870e7f72a6dbd

Comment: Hey man, can you add one more edit that includes all the code you have thus far? That error shouldn't be too hard to figure out at this point.

Comment: I have posted another answer with your code so it's more clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75429/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-elomar-adam).

Answer (score 2):

If you want one form put the form tags outside the while loop

```
 <?php
        $sql = "SELECT IDBewoner, Foto FROM Bewoners LIMIT 5";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $totaalbewoners = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        ?> 
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ?>
        <tr>

                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>" name="bewoner"></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['Foto'])."' width='90' height='90'>" ?> </td>

            <td> 
                    <div id="rang1" class="DropZone"></div> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang1value" />
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <div id="rang2" class="DropZone"></div> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang2value" />
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <div id="rang3" class="DropZone"></div> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang3value" />
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <div id="rang4" class="DropZone"></div> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang4value" />
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <div id="rang5" class="DropZone"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang5value" />
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <div id="rang6" class="DropZone"></div> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="6" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang6value" />
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <div id="rang7" class="DropZone"></div> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="7" name="rang_input[][]" id="rang7value" />
                </td>

    <?php };?>
       <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </form> 
            </tr>
    <?php    

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         foreach ($_POST['rang_input'] as $key => $value) {
                 foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
                  echo $value1 . "<br />";
                 }
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No it doesn't really work.. I'm still getting only the first row

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do ?

```
$values = array;
for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++)
{ 
   $values [$i] = $_POST["rang".$i."value"];
}
```

Comment: Not really. For each row (resident) I have 7 input fields (from rang1value to rang7value). When I submit the form I only get the first seven inputs and I need to get all the seven inputs for all the residents. Do you understand what I mean or should i try to explain it more?

Comment: You mean you have several owners

Comment: Yes indeed and for each one of them there are 7 inputs.

Answer (score 1):

How about this then ?  Assuming your inputs have ids own1rang1value, own1rang2value etc

```
$values = array; 
for ($owner=1; $owner<=7; $owner++)
{
   $rec = array;
   for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++)
   { 
      $rec [$i] = $_POST["own".$owner."rang".$i."value"];
   }
   $values[$owner]=$rec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inserting code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $sql['cols']    =   "INSERT INTO ActiviteitenSchema (DagVanDeWeek, Bewoner, Activiteit, DatumAangemaakt, Rangnr) VALUES";

    $i = 0;
    foreach($_POST['rang'] as $key => $value) {             
        $z = 0;
        foreach($value as $rang) {
            if(!empty($rang)) {
                    $vals[$i][] = "(4, '".$_POST['bewoner'][$i]."', '".$rang."', '2015-04-14', '$z')";
            }
            $z++;
        }

        if(isset($vals[$i])) {
            $sql['vals'][]  =   implode(", ",$vals[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($sql['vals'])) {
        $statement  =   $sql['cols'].implode(", ",$sql['vals']);
        $res        =   $mysqli->query($statement);
        echo "<script>alert('gegevens zijn toegevoegd')</script>";
        header("Location: nieuwschema.php");
    }
}

?>
```

The fetch_assoc:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
  <div id="ListBewoners">
      <table id="ListBewonersUL">

      <?php
      $sql = "SELECT IDBewoner, Foto FROM Bewoners LIMIT 5";
      $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
      $totaalbewoners = mysqli_num_rows($res);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      ?>
      <tr>
          <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
              <td>
                  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>" name="bewoner[]" size="2">
              </td>
              <td>
                  <?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Foto']); ?>" width='90' height='90'>
              </td>
              <?php for($i=0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                  $owner_id   =   $i.$row["IDBewoner"]; ?>
              <td> 
                  <div id="rang<?php echo $owner_id; ?>" class="DropZone"></div> 
                  <input type="text" value="" id="rang<?php echo $owner_id; ?>input" name="rang[<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"]; ?>][<?php echo $i; ?>]" />
              </td>
              <?php }
          } ?>
      </tr><tr>
              <td>
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
              </td>
          </form>
      </tr>


  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the action as `PHP_SELF` and put the inserting code in the same page at the bottom.